# nfSen stops working after Stretch/Debian 9 upgrade

Tags: debian, nfsen

After an upgrade to Debian 9, and substituting PHP5 for PHP7, my open source netflow collector nfSen was apparently working, however after a restart of the server, it stopped working.

The error it is giving, when opening the main page is:

> ERROR: nfsend connect() error: Connection refused!
>   ERROR: nfsend - connection failed!!
>   ERROR: Can not initialize globals!

What to do?

After debugging a little more, `nfsend` is giving an error "PANIC nfsend dies: RRD version '1.5001' not yet supported!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the nfSen mailing list: https://sourceforge.net/p/nfsen/mailman/message/34904261/

> I updated and had to edit `/usr/local/libexec/nfsen/NfSenRRD.pm` line
>   76 to be:
>
> ```
> ( $rrd_version >= 1.2 && $rrd_version < 1.6 )
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> ( $rrd_version >= 1.2 && $rrd_version < 1.5 )
> ```

This patch corrected the problem and allowed me to login into nfSen. 
If seems nfSen as it was did not support rrdtools 1.6.0, as they are coming with Stretch.

It should be also noted that while this was not corrected, while nfSen collected netflows, it did not update the corresponding RRD graphics.